# Python 2 to Python 3: Script wont execute properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I made this script its for checking if the github profiles contain email and sort them i 2 separate list, it not finished need to optimize and get rid of extra stuff.

The main problem is that i was running with terminal using python, and that 2.7 by my system, when I wanted to run it with python 3 , I got errors, I tried debugging them but still couldn't fix the problem.

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from timeit import default_timer as timer

start = timer()

timeout = 1

haveEmail = []
noEmail = []

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("headless")

#YOU NEED TO PROVIDE THE LOCATION OF YOU CHROME DRIVER
browser = webdriver.Chrome('/home/djurovic/Desktop/Linux ChromeDriver/chromedriver', chrome_options=options)

def login(email):
    browser.get(email)

    signInXpath = '//a[@class="HeaderMenu-link no-underline mr-3"]'
    signInElement = WebDriverWait(browser, timeout).until(lambda browser: browser.find_element_by_xpath(signInXpath))
    signInElement.click()

    #ENTER YOUR LOGIN INFORMATION
    username = ''
    password = ''

    userNameXpath = '//input[@class="form-control input-block"]'
    passwordXpath = '//input[@class="form-control form-control input-block"]'
    loginButtonXpath = '//input[@class="btn btn-primary btn-block"]'

    userNameElement = WebDriverWait(browser, timeout).until(lambda browser: browser.find_element_by_xpath(userNameXpath))
    passwordElement = WebDriverWait(browser, timeout).until(lambda browser: browser.find_element_by_xpath(passwordXpath))

    userNameElement.clear()
    userNameElement.send_keys(username)
    passwordElement.clear()
    passwordElement.send_keys(password)

    loginButtonElement = WebDriverWait(browser, timeout).until(lambda browser: browser.find_element_by_xpath(loginButtonXpath))
    loginButtonElement.click()

def checkEmail(profile):
    browser.get(profile)
    emailXPath = '//a[@class="u-email"]'
    try:
        emailElement = WebDriverWait(browser, timeout).until(lambda browser: browser.find_element_by_xpath(emailXPath))
        haveEmail.append(profile)
    except:
        noEmail.append(profile)

def parse():
    i = 1
    document = open('profiles.txt', 'rb')
    for profile in document:
        if i == 1:
            login(profile)
            i = i + 1
        checkEmail(profile)      
    browser.close()

parse()

print(haveEmail)
print(noEmail)

for item in haveEmail:
    output_file = open("profiles_with_email.txt", 'a')
    for i in str(len(haveEmail)):
        output_file.write(item + "\n")
    output_file.close()

for item in noEmail:
    output_file = open("profiles_with_no_email.txt", 'a')
    for i in str(len(noEmail)):
        output_file.write(item + "\n")
    output_file.close()


elapsed_time = timer() - start
print("Script finished in " + str(elapsed_time))
```

Here are the errors that I get when run it through python 3 :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "github.py", line 77, in <module>
    parse()
  File "github.py", line 72, in parse
    login(profile)
  File "github.py", line 33, in login
    browser.get(email)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 333, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 319, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 372, in execute
    data = utils.dump_json(params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/utils.py", line 33, in dump_json
    return json.dumps(json_struct)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 231, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 180, in default
    o.__class__.__name__)
TypeError: Object of type 'bytes' is not JSON serializable
```

Any kind of help would be a lot of help!!!

Comment: can you print `profile` value? in `parse` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @ZeroQ and @Divyanshu Srivastava

I've tried @Divyanshu Srivastava, but that function can't take an extra argument, so I've just added in my parse() function this line :

```
profile = profile.decode('utf-8')
```

And it works as a charm.
Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Try opening your `profile.txt` file in unicode.

```
document = open('profiles.txt', 'rb', encoding="utf-8")
```

Please also refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36212905/python-3-is-not-json-serializable) post.

**EDIT**

We cant encoding file opened in binary mode.The whole purpose of encoding is to represent data as characters. Binary mode by definition does not require an encoding. 
We can remove `b` from the argument, like

```
document = open('profiles.txt', 'r', encoding="utf-8")
```

We can also encode the `profile` variable in `my_parse' function (as suggested by [stefan]) as

```
profile = profile.decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: This what I get : ValueError: binary mode doesn't take an encoding argument

Answer (score 1):

You need to properly encode your data that you read from `profiles.txt`. In Python3 it is bytes and that is not serializable to JSON.

So the `profile` variable contains a byte representation of the GitHub profile URL and not a string representation. I believe you need to change this.